# Pros/Cons of different ASP.NET Caching Options

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-web-api

I recently asked a question about caching application data in an ASP.NET MVC WebAPI application and it led me to a new question. What are the pros/cons of different caching methods available in ASP.NET?

I have come upon:

- Memory Cache

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx
- Using Static Member Variables:

  ```
  private static Northwind.SuppliersDataTable suppliers = null;
  ```
- Application State:

  ```
   HttpContext.Current.Application["key"] ="Value"
  ```
- Data Cache:

  ```
  HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
    /* key */                "key", 
    /* value */              "value", 
    /* dependencies */       null, 
    /* absoluteExpiration */ Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
    /* slidingExpiration */  Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
    /* priority */           CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, 
    /* onRemoveCallback */   null);
  ```

I am sure there are others, and I know they all technically store the data in memory...so any idea what I should use for an ASP.NET MVC webapi?

My Previous Question:
[Caching application data in memory: MVC Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937545/caching-application-data-in-memory-mvc-web-api)

Comment: It depends, you could say what you want to do, but, I do not like the `Application` entries. I preffer using an `IDictionary<string, object>`. `Cache` is fine if you can remake your data.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Each Caching technology/methods have their own set of features. These features may seem to be of disadvantage in one application requirements but can be advantageous in other application requirements.

So, in short , depending on your requirements decide which Caching technology and what features are best for you.

***`For example, Let us discuss some client side Caching techniques`.***

MSDN says that we can also use `HiddenField` to store only small amounts of frequently changing data in hidden fields because this data is included in the roundtrips to the server on every postback.

***Advantage of this feature:*** Reduces the workload on your server by storing page information using client-side options.

However,  MSDN says clearly that : This approach has minimal security support.

Thus, one may or may not use this feature always as security considerations are also there.

***`Consider one more example`***, **`Page Output caching`** : it is of 2 types, page output caching and page fragment caching.

Page output caching caches an entire Web page and is suitable only when the content of that page is fairly static. If parts of the page are changing, you can wrap the static sections as user controls and cache the user controls using page fragment caching.

***`And one last comment on`*** `Application`  vs `HttpRuntime.cache`:

`Application` is not a cache, its a global named value collection. if you add an object to `Application` it will stay until a an appdomain recycle.

- Application variables are shared variables among all users of a web application
- Application variables behave like static variables and they are substitute of static variables as static variables are stateless in web applications
- Only shared values should be persisted in Application variables, and as soon as they are not in use they should be removed explicitly.

`Cache` :It is possible to obtain significant performance improvements in ASP.NET applications by caching frequently requested objects and data in either the `Application` or `Cache` classes. While the `Cache` class certainly offers far more flexibility and control, it only appears to offer a marginal advantage in terms of increased throughput over the `Application` class for caching. It would be very difficult to develop a testing scheme that could accurately measure the potential advantages of the `Cache` class's built - in management of lesser-used objects through the scavenging process as opposed to the fact that Application does not offer this feature.  The  developer needs to take decision in this case and should be based on the needs and convenience of the project and its usage patterns. Check ***[this link](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030405.asp)*** for more.

Refer ***[this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957905.aspx)*** for a complete great explanation on all Caching technologies in Asp.net with discusiion on the features of each technology.

Also, these 2 links are a great source to start with:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/httpruntime-cache-vs-httpcontext-current-cache
- http://devshop.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/how-to-choose-from-viewstate-sessionstate-cookies-and-cache/

Comment: Awesome overview ! Although your comment is directed primarily at asp.net websites and not the webapi, the msdn web article you listed has a lot of amazing info.

Comment: @Interstellar: Links usually stop working ... I tried to include as many details as possible in my answer. But didn't wanted it to be lengthy to much. The MSDN link and the Very first link is working fine which does contains most of the valuable information. You can else search on Peter Johnson's Blog for any Content Here: https://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson

Comment: ***http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/02/06/437559.aspx*** http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/437559 not found

Comment: Fix Link by _P Johnson_: ***https://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/httpruntime-cache-vs-httpcontext-current-cache***

Answer (score 10):

Regarding `MemoryCache` vs ASP.NET Cache: they provide very similar functionality.  In an ASP.NET 4 application, I'd generally prefer the ASP.NET Cache, if for no other reason, then because of [a bug in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422859/memorycache-disposed-in-web-application), which is apparently fixed in .NET 4.5.

Static fields are appropriate to store shared data that does not need an expiration policy.

Application state isn't much more than a static dictionary with locking semantics that is compatible with classic ASP - I'd only use it for backwards compatibility with legacy classic ASP code.

Comment: Do you know if either of these cache methods are persistent across IIS worker thread timeouts ?

Comment: @vesuvious - yes, they will all persist across a request timeout: such a timeout has no effect on static fields.  They will be cleared when the application domain is recycled.

Answer (score 4):

When using Web API your first choice for caching should always be to set the caching headers in the HTTP response.  `HttpResponseMessage.CacheControlHeader`.

Your last options should be anything that depends on `HttpContext` or `HttpRuntime`, as that will tie you to particular hosts.  Web API applications should be built independent of their host.

Comment: you mean last options should *not* be?

Comment: @user20358 I mean you should try and use host independent optimizations first before trying to optimize using mechanisms that are dependent on the host.