# Caching in C# to improve performance[ASP.Net MVC]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have a function in controller which returns a list of countries.I am trying to implement caching in it..so that list is fetched only when empty at server side.I found two ways:

1. Using **OutputCache**

   ```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 86400, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server,VaryByParam ="none")]
    public function getelement(){
    //return list of country;
    }
   ```

But I am not able to test it maybe because both client and server is myself in this.

2. Using **MemoryCache**

   ```
    private static MemoryCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

   _cache.Add(cacheKey, obj, policy);//MemoryCache(String, NameValueCollection, Boolean)
   ```

I am not able to correctly implement 2nd one.

Any suggestions?

**Update 1:**

```
   ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
            string cacheKey = "countrylist";
            var cacheObject = cache.Get(cacheKey);

            if (cacheObject == null)
            {
                cacheObject = getelement();//returns a list of string type
                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(60);
                cache.Add(cacheKey, cacheObject, policy);

            }
```

I am not able to use cacheObject or access  the list which  now is of object type.

I tried following solutions:

```
1. var mylist = (from p in cacheObject.Cast<string>(IQueryable) select p).ToList();


2. List<string> mylist = cacheObject.AsQueryable().Cast<string>().Select(values).ToList();
 values.AddRange(mylist);
```

But I am not able to create a list of string type :(

Comment: On which level do you want to add some cache layer? On controllers?

Comment: yes..on controller

Comment: One advantage of `OutputCache` is the ability to do client-side (i.e. browser caching) - which means the browser doesn't need to ask for the resource from your server. Is that of use to you?

Comment: I guess no..cause I am trying to reduce the first time pageload time..and that wont make any differnce..its better to save the list in server's cache

Comment: `its better to save the list in server's cache` `OutputCache` can do **both** (client and server caching). Plus it can cache on any downstream server (e.g. proxy - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation(v=vs.110).aspx). Plus if you later add a CDN you will get improved load times again. Honestly, if you are trying to cache the entire http request you should strongly consider `OutputCache`. That is what it is for.

Comment: How many web servers are you running? Are you using a web farm or web garden?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pros/Cons of different ASP.NET Caching Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937855/pros-cons-of-different-asp-net-caching-options)

Answer (score 1):

`MemoryCache.Default` is already static, there is no need to store it again.

You can implement similar to this:

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
var cacheObject = cache.Get(cacheKey);

if (cacheObject == null)
{
    cacheObject = //do something to get it
    CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(2);
    cache.Add(cacheKey, cacheObject, policy);
}
return cacheObject;
```

> Update

To @mjwills point, if you have a web farm/load balanced site each server will hold it's own cache and they could be out of sync (for at least the duration of the expiration) between servers. You might be OK with this, or you might not. If not consider NCache, Redis, or similar product.

Comment: I have a list of countries..how to set cacheobject or cachekey?

Comment: `cacheObject = <your list of countries>;` . You can also make this a generic method and return `(T)cacheObject` if you don't want to cast in the caller.

Comment: and cachekey? its a type of string.

Comment: Yes, `cachekey` is how you will refer to the object in the cache. Be sure to use a logical and unique value because subtle bugs can occur if you re-use keys for different cache objects.